# ASP.NET MVC Syncfusion Data Grid Displays Locally But Not In Azure Deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, syncfusion

I am building an ASP.NET MVC app with a Syncfusion Grid on a page. The Grid uses, as its data source, a SQL Azure database accessed through the Entity Framework. I can run the app in both Debug and Release mode in my development environment and all is well.

However, when I deploy the site to Azure, the Grid has no data. When I "View Source" on the page, I can see the SQL Azure data in the source, so I know the connection to SQL Azure is good. Also, the grid footer displays the correct number of records in the footer, so that is correct as well. The Grid does not display the "There are no records to display" message in Azure. It just has the column headers and then the footer.

The only other difference that I have noticed is that I have the Column Chooser enabled for the Grid, and the drop-down button for the Column Chooser appears locally but is missing from the Azure deployment.

I've tried to deploy using the Web Deploy feature in Visual Studio, as well as the Continuous Deployment Preview feature in the Azure Portal to no avail.

Does anyone know what is going on? The Azure-deployed page is [here](https://lorri.azurewebsites.net/Dashboard) if you'd like to see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was missing `jsrender.min.js` in my `/Scripts` directory. The local deployment found the `jsrender.min.js` script elsewhere in my machine, apparently, but the production Azure deployment was specifically looking for it in the `/Scripts` folder.

I copied `jsrender.min.js` into the `/Scripts` folder, deployed back to Azure, and, after that, all was well.